# How to produce error msg on ambiguous column names?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter a lot lately, with array methods for querying data: usually `result_array()` or `row_array()` DB methods. I noticed a mistake that sometimes happens without error notices (old code - not mine - I'm just the bug fixer). It's the typical ambiguous column name issue that has been posted many times here in StackOverflow.

For example: 
[PHP & MYSQL: How to resolve ambiguous column names in JOIN operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431391/php-mysql-how-to-resolve-ambiguous-column-names-in-join-operation)

With CodeIgniter, there's no ambiguous field error message. The array is populated as usual with the field names; ambiguous or not. Is there anyway to prevent this from within CodeIgnitier by displaying or logging an error message?

Does anyone have any ideas on how to log an error message (using CI `log_message()` perhaps) with PHP when ambiguous fields issues arise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. The reason that CI doesn't throw up SQL errors about ambiguous column names is because it appends the name of the table when selecting so for example

```
SELECT `table`.`name`, `table2`.`name` FROM `table`, `table2` ...
```

The reason you then don't get to see these columns is because the array key generated by `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` or whichever driver you're using is `name` for both and obviously gets overwritten. The following answer is suitable for those using CI2.x.

Extend the Database driver result class in a similar fashion used in my answer to [CodeIgniter: SQL Audit of all $this->db->query() method calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893996/codeigniter-sql-audit-of-all-this-db-query-method-calls/7894047#7894047). Once you've extended the database driver result class you have two options. You can throw an error as you requested as follows:

```
/**
 * Result - associative array
 *
 * Returns the result set as an array
 *
 * @access  private
 * @return  array
 */
function _fetch_assoc()
{
    if (!($row = mysql_fetch_array($this->result_id)))
    {
        return null;
    }

    $return = array();
    $row_count = mysql_num_fields($this->result_id);

    for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++)
    {
        $field = mysql_field_name($this->result_id, $i);

        if( array_key_exists( $field, $return ) ) {
            log_message('Error message about ambiguous columns here');
        } else {
            $return[$field] = $row[$i];
        }
    }

    return $return;

    //Standard CI implementation
    //return mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result_id);
}
```

Or alternatively you can further manipulate the output of the function to simulate the query behavior by prepending `tablename_` to the column name resulting in an array like

```
SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `companies` ON `users`.`id` = `companies`.`id`
Array (
    [users_id] => 1
    [users_name] => User1
    [companies_id] => 1
    [companies_name] => basdasd
    [companies_share_price] => 10.00
)
```

To achieve this you can simply modify the `for` loop in the above function to the following:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++)
{
    $table = mysql_field_table($this->result_id, $i);
    $field = mysql_field_name($this->result_id, $i);
    $return["$table_$field"] = $row[$i];
}
```

Comment: Nice response, thank you for the effort explaining all of that!

Comment: Just read your comment and spotted a bug in my code. $result should be $this->result_id. Will fix when at a computer. No problem though, you're welcome

Comment: Fixed, all $result variables have been replaced with $this->result_id